# Повторяющаяся аннотация Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, аннотации

В моем коде в двух местах употребляется следующая конструкция:

```
if typing.TYPE_CHECKING:
    from queue import Queue as ThreadingQueue
    from gevent.queue import Queue as GeventQueue
    from multiprocessing import MultiprocessingQueue

queue: typing.Union['MultiprocessingQueue', 'ThreadingQueue', 'GeventQueue']
```

Мне захотелось избавиться от дублирования и вынести это в файл настроек(не знаю, стоит ли так вообще делать, поправьте в комментариях, пожалуйста)

Я сделал следующее:

```
queue = Union['MultiprocessingQueue', 'ThreadingQueue', 'GeventQueue']
```

Но вот момент, пайчарм подчеркивает мне импорты после if TYPE_CHECKING серым цветом, что свидетельствует о том, что они не используются, но при удалении их после подчеркивает, что я передаю объект не того типа.
Действенный вариант передавать в юнион сами объекты, без использования тайпчекинга, но кроме как в тайпхинтингах эти объекты не будут использоваться.

Comment: Пробовали так? `Queue = Union['MultiprocessingQueue', 'ThreadingQueue', 'GeventQueue']`, потом в коде `queue: Queue`. И еще убрать условие `if typing.TYPE_CHECKING:`, просто всегда импортировать.

Comment: if TYPE_CHECKING серым подчеркивает потому что с точки зрения PyCharm там всегда False, поэтому он этот блок выделяет как "мертвый код". Если в остальном все работает, то можно это выделение серым игнорировать.

Comment: @insolor если после TYPE_CHECKING использовать импорты в аннотациях в кавычках, то они перестают быть серыми, а вот если присваивать аннотацию переменной, то все работает не так

Comment: @insolor и есть ли смысл импортировать всегда, если кроме как в аннотациях не используется импорт?

Comment: Ну смотрите, все работает же: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Okk6E.png На то что строки стали серыми просто не обращайте внимания.

Comment: Как вариант добавьте '# noqa' в конце каждой строчки с импортом. pycharm и pylint будут игнорировать.

Comment: @insolor оки, спасибо, если хотите, внесите это в ответ, я отмечу решением

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В отдельном модуле объявляете тип `Queue`:

```
import typing

if typing.TYPE_CHECKING:
    from queue import Queue as ThreadingQueue  # noqa
    from gevent.queue import Queue as GeventQueue  # noqa
    from multiprocessing import Queue as MultiprocessingQueue  # noqa

Queue = typing.Union['MultiprocessingQueue', 'ThreadingQueue', 'GeventQueue']
```

Комментарии `# noqa` добавлены, чтобы статические анализаторы кода (в том числе встроенный в PyCharm) не считали импорты неиспользуемыми (неиспользуемые импорты может при коммите удалить PyCharm, если в окне коммита не убрать галку "оптимизировать импорты"). Предложено участником [@Roman Konoval](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/218971).

В коде, где нужна аннотация с типом `Queue`, импортируем ее и пользуемся:

```
# Вместо module_name вставить имя модуля, где объявили тип Queue
from module_name import Queue

queue: Queue

queue = 123  # Статический анализатор покажет ошибку типов
```